Apache5HttpClientBuilderConfigurator not working with JerseyClient
I am trying to combine some attribute from Apache 5 HTTP with Jersey 3.
My Apache5HttpClientBuilderConfigurator:
       Apache5HttpClientBuilderConfigurator apache5HttpClientBuilderConfigurator = (builder) ->
                builder
                        .evictExpiredConnections()
                        .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                        .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                        .evictIdleConnections(TimeValue.ofSeconds(5))
                        .disableConnectionState()
                        .disableAutomaticRetries();

        RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setConnectTimeout(Timeout.ofMilliseconds(getTimeout()))
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(Timeout.ofMilliseconds(getRequestTimeout()))
                .setResponseTimeout(Timeout.ofMilliseconds(getSoTimeout()))
                .build();

ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
clientConfig .register(apache5HttpClientBuilderConfigurator);
clientConfig .connectorProvider(new Apache5ConnectorProvider());

JerseyClientBuilder.createClient(clientConfig);

I can see that the Jersey builder is registered with Apache5ConnectorProvider. But other the Apache5HttpClientBuilderConfigurator is not working though
.I am aware that I can use ClientConfig to register withRequestConfig. But I do need other settings from HTTP Client which are not available
Do you guys have any suggestions?
